# Mapping through Starwars API by planet Name in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, mapping

I am currently trying to map through every planet in the star wars api and print out the individual planet name but I am stuck. API LINK (https://swapi.dev/)

Thankyou for any help or advice

I tried using axios and Use Effect but am not sure where my errors may be. Below is what i have in my AllPlanets React Component.

`

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const AllPlanets = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets`)
      .then((res) => setData(res.data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {data && (
        <div className="flex">
          {data.map((planet, idx) => (
            <p>{planet.name}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllPlanets;
```

`

Answer (score 2):

These are the needed fixes (see comments in code as well):

- The API response contains the property `results` that has the actual list of planets
- The `useEffect` needs an empty dependencies array to block it from running on each render, and creating an infinite loop
- Each item in an rendered list needs a key with a unique value

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const AllPlanets = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets`)
      .then(res => setData(res.data.results)) // get the results property from the res.data object
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []); // add a dependency array so you won't have an infinite loop

  return (
    <div>
      {!!data.length && (
        <div className="flex">
          {data.map(({ name }) => (
            // use the name as key
            <p key={name}>{name}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<AllPlanets />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.3/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-0qU9M9jfqPw6FKkPafM3gy2CBAvUWnYVOfNPDYKVuRTel1PrciTj+a9P3loJB+j0QmN2Y0JYQmkBBS8W+mbezg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much ! Your bullet points at the start and the comments helped a ton !

Comment: It would better to initialize your state as an empty array.